# If statement syntax error in JS

Tags: javascript, syntax

I am trying to use an if/else and I can't figure out where I'm going wrong with the syntax. I want the `payload` to only submit `school_ids` if the `role` isn't `p_admin`. Thank you for your help!

```
const createUser = (payload) => request.postJSON(
    '/register',
    excludeObjNullValue({
        username: payload.username,
        email: payload.email,
        password: payload.password,
        first_name: payload.firstName,
        last_name: payload.lastName,
        role: payload.role,
        district_id: payload.districtId,
        if (role !== 'p_admin'){
        school_ids: payload.schoolIds
        }
    })
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see 2-3 options depending on your `excludeObjNullValue` function:

1. You can either break that expression up in to a couple of statements, or
2. Or use property spread notation and the conditional operator, or
3. If `excludeObjNullValue` does what the name suggests, you can use a conditional *without* spread notation and rely on `excludeObjNullValue` to exclude it

Option 3 may well be your best bet, but I'll give them in order:

#### Option 1: The multi-statement way:

```
const createUser = (payload) => {
    const options = {
        username: payload.username,
        email: payload.email,
        password: payload.password,
        first_name: payload.firstName,
        last_name: payload.lastName,
        role: payload.role,
        district_id: payload.districtId,
    };
    if (role !== 'p_admin') {
        options.school_ids = payload.schoolIds;
    }
    return request.postJSON('/register', excludeObjNullValue(options));
};
```

#### Option 2: Property spread and the conditional operator

[Property spread](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) is a Stage 3 proposal but support for it is already shipping in Chrome and Firefox, and if you're transpiling you can tell your transpiler to support it. That would look like this:

```
const createUser = (payload) => request.postJSON(
    '/register',
    excludeObjNullValue({
        username: payload.username,
        email: payload.email,
        password: payload.password,
        first_name: payload.firstName,
        last_name: payload.lastName,
        role: payload.role,
        district_id: payload.districtId,
        {...(role !== 'p_admin' ? {school_ids: payload.schoolIds} : {}}
        }
    })
);
```

Whether it's a good idea even if supported is your call. :-) It does briefly create an extra object and iterator.

#### Option 3: Rely on `excludeObjNullValue` to exclude properties with `null` values:

If it really does what the name suggests, then it will remove `school_ids` if we give the value `null` to it. So:

```
const createUser = (payload) => request.postJSON(
    '/register',
    excludeObjNullValue({
        username: payload.username,
        email: payload.email,
        password: payload.password,
        first_name: payload.firstName,
        last_name: payload.lastName,
        role: payload.role,
        district_id: payload.districtId,
        school_ids: role !== 'p_admin' ? payload.schoolIds : null
        }
    })
);
```

Comment: *(If you see -- or rather **don't** see -- a missing `)` in the first code block at the end, hit refresh.)*

Comment: In JS, is an inline expression valid? i.e., `school_ids: payload.role !== 'p_admin' ? payload.schoolIds : ""`

Comment: @MetroSmurf: That would still submit `school_ids`, it would just submit it either with the value `payload.schoolIds` or `""`.

Comment: Guess I didn't read the question correctly, re: only include the property when the condition exists. As opposed to include the property with a value or some default value.

Comment: @MetroSmurf: That said, they are passing that object into a function called `excludeObjNullValue`, which if it does what the name suggests, means we could use `school_ids: role !== 'p_admin' ? payload.schoolIds : null` and rely on `excludeObjNullValue` to exclude the property if its value is `null`. :-) I added it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't write `if` statement at the object declaration. Also you need to explicitly defined body for your arrow function. So you can do something like

```
const createUser = (payload) => {
   const obj = {
      username: payload.username,
        email: payload.email,
        password: payload.password,
        first_name: payload.firstName,
        last_name: payload.lastName,
        role: payload.role,
        district_id: payload.districtId
   };

   if(obj.role !== 'p_admin') {
      obj.school_ids = payload.schoolIds
   }

   return request.postJSON('/register', excludeObjNullValue(obj));

}
```